# How to mock private method of another Class other than the Class under test using PowerMock?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, mockito, powermock

I have a class which I would like to test with a public method that calls the private method of another class. When I try calling the private method of the same class, everything works perfectly. The problem occours when I try to mock another private method that gets called from the class under test. Following is the code sample of the test class.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({CodeWithPrivateMethod.class,CodeWithAnotherPrivateMethod.class})
public class CodeWithPrivateMethodTest {

    @Test
    public void when_gambling_is_true_then_always_explode() throws Exception {
        CodeWithPrivateMethod spy = PowerMockito.spy(new CodeWithPrivateMethod());
        CodeWithAnotherPrivateMethod codeWithAnotherPrivateMethod = PowerMockito.spy(new CodeWithAnotherPrivateMethod());      

        /*when(codeWithAnotherPrivateMethod, method(CodeWithAnotherPrivateMethod.class, "doTheGame", String.class))
                .withArguments(anyString())
                .thenReturn(true);*/

        PowerMockito.when(codeWithAnotherPrivateMethod, "doTheGame", anyString()).thenReturn(true);
        //PowerMockito.doReturn(true).when(codeWithAnotherPrivateMethod, "doTheGamble", anyString(),anyInt());

        spy.meaningfulPublicApi();
    }
}
```

Following is the code sample for the class under test

```
import java.util.Random;

public class CodeWithPrivateMethod {

    CodeWithAnotherPrivateMethod anotherPrivateMethod = new CodeWithAnotherPrivateMethod();

    public void meaningfulPublicApi() {
        if (anotherPrivateMethod.doTheGame("Whatever")) {
            System.out.println("kaboom");
        }
    } 
}
```

And Following is the code sample for the class that gets called from the class under test

```
import java.util.Random;

public class CodeWithAnotherPrivateMethod {

    public boolean doTheGame(String string) {
        return doTheGamble("Whatever", 1 << 3);
    }

    private boolean doTheGamble(String whatever, int binary) {
        Random random = new Random(System.nanoTime());
        boolean gamble = random.nextBoolean();
        return gamble;
    }
}
```

So My Question is how do i succesfully mock doTheGamble() method of CodeWithAnotherPrivateMethod Class to make it return true always?

Comment: Might be easier to read if you remove the comments. I'd think that once you created an instance of you class under test (`CodeWithPrivateMethod`) and you created a mock itself (`CodeWithAnotherPrivateMethod`), you just set the private instance within your class under test to be the mocked object (check `Whitebox` for helping with that).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is although you are creating a spy of `CodeWithAnotherPrivateMethod` in your test, a new instance of `CodeWithAnotherPrivateMethod` is created in `CodeWithPrivateMethod`. So, actually you are not using your mock.

```
CodeWithAnotherPrivateMethod anotherPrivateMethod = new CodeWithAnotherPrivateMethod();
```

To avoid this, you can force to return your CodeWithAnotherPrivateMethod mock when a new instance is created. You can use PowerMockito [`whenNew()`](https://powermock.googlecode.com/svn/docs/powermock-1.5/apidocs/org/powermock/api/mockito/PowerMockito.html#whenNew(java.lang.Class)) capability to do this.

Example:

```
PowerMockito.whenNew(CodeWithAnotherPrivateMethod.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(codeWithAnotherPrivateMethod);
```

Finally, your test should be something like this:

```
@Test
public void when_gambling_is_true_then_always_explode() throws Exception {
  // Spy CodeWithAnotherPrivateMethod and force return true when doTheGamble is called
  CodeWithAnotherPrivateMethod codeWithAnotherPrivateMethod = PowerMockito.spy(new CodeWithAnotherPrivateMethod());
  PowerMockito.doReturn(true).when(codeWithAnotherPrivateMethod, "doTheGamble", Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyInt());
  // Return your mock when a new instance of CodeWithAnotherPrivateMethod is created.
  PowerMockito.whenNew(CodeWithAnotherPrivateMethod.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(codeWithAnotherPrivateMethod);

  CodeWithPrivateMethod spy = PowerMockito.spy(new CodeWithPrivateMethod());
  spy.meaningfulPublicApi();
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, that works like a charm. But it looks like i'm still confused about mocking. Also a quick question, whenever i spy the CodeWithPrivateMethod Class before spying on CodeWithAnotherPrivateMethod Class, the result don't turn out to be as expected. Why does this happen could you please explain?

Comment: Glad to help :) That's because when you spy CodeWithPrivateMethod, a new instance is created, so at this moment, is also created the new instance of CodeWithAnotherPrivateMethod (and this is still not mocked, so the instance is a 'real' CodeWithAnotherPrivateMethod object).

Comment: fair enough :) looks like I have a long way to go :D